# Effect size in OLS Python statsmodels

Tags: least-squares, effect-size, statsmodels

I have fitted an OLS model in Python statsmodels and have the following output:
[image]

How can I calculate the effect size for each of the independent variables using Python statsmodels?

Comment: Which effect size? There are many different ones. They are not yet included in statsmodels, but some can be computed from the available results.

Comment: As far as I understand Cohens f square makes sense for Linear Regression. Is it possible to calculate this?

Comment: I think something like `f = tvalues**2 / df_resid` computes the partial effect size for each variable. (no guarantees that I remember correctly and I don't find the articles). (Aside: work in progress for statsmodels https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5896 )

Comment: Another way would be to compute partial eta and similar from the anova table, `anova_lm`